# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$ is connected without path connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Prove that $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$ is connected.

First of all, I know this was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589765/proving-mathbb-r2-setminus-mathbb-q2-is-connected) [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17460/connectedness-of-sets-in-the-plane-with-rational-coordinates-and-at-least-one-irr) [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135660/connectedness-of-points-with-both-rational-or-irrational-coordinates-in-the-plan) [over](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516916/mathbbr-mathbbq-and-mathbbr2-setminus-mathbbq2-disconnected) in this site.

However I'm looking for a proof that does not use path-connectedness (which I know, but this exercise is from a previous lecture), nor the knowledge that $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash E$, where $E$ is countable, is connected (it's the second part of the exercise).

I tried using disjoint open sets and separated sets, and also using the fact that they should also be the intersection of sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$, but I hit a wall there.

I have the feeling I'm forgetting something very basic and obvious, or I may be overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**:

Suppose there are two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ whose union is all of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Consider any line $L$ of the form $\{p\} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R} \times \{p\}$ for $p \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Show that $L \subset U$ or $L \subset V$.

(Hint: $U \cap L$ and $V \cap L$ are open subsets of $L$ in the subspace topology.)

Comment: ah, I think you beat me to it. :) +1

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes, noticed yours showed up at about the same time. Good to have slightly different takes on the idea =). +1 to you as well.

Comment: Got it done. Thanks for both of you!

Comment: @aes one of the intersection must be empty. How do we proceed next?

Comment: @MathMan: Suppose $U\cap L=\emptyset$. Then, $L\subset U^c=V.$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Assume $T := \mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2 = U \cup V$ is a disjoint union of nonempty open subsets.

Since $\mathbb R \times \{\pi\} \subset T$ is connected, it must be a subset of either $U$ or $V$. Say it's contained in $U$. Now show that $\{r\} \times \mathbb R \subset U$ for every irrational $r$, and that $\mathbb R \times \{r\} \subset U$ as well.