# Which of the following sets are connected? NBHM 2018

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

[image]

a. This set is clearly disconnected because Determinant map is a continuous function from $\mathcal{O}_n(\mathbb{R})$ to the discrete set $\{1, -1\}$

c. This set can be thought as $\mathbb{R^2}-\mathbb{Q^2}$ which is connected as poved here [Proving $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Q^2$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589765/proving-mathbb-r2-setminus-mathbb-q2-is-connected?rq=1)

b. I'm confused with this option and can't think of any possible ways to justify. Please give some hint. Thank you.

Comment: Convexity${{}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints for (b):

Let $f,g \in S$.

Let $p:[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ be defined by
$$p(t)=(1-t)f+tg$$

Show that $p$ is continuous.

Show that the image of $p$ is a subset of $S$.

Note that $p(0)=f$, and $p(1)=g$.

Deduce that $S$ is path-connected.